# A fiber bundle with trivial structure group is (isomorphic) to a trivial bundle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

How do I show that a fiber bundle with trivial structure group is (isomorphic to) a trivial bundle?

I say let $\phi$ and $\phi'$ be two charts over $U$. Then $\phi=\phi'$ since there is a continuous function $\theta_{\phi,\phi'}:U\to \{e\}$ such that $\phi'(u,f)=\phi(u,\theta_{\phi,\phi'}(u)\cdot f)=\phi(u,e\cdot f)=\phi(u,f)$ for all $u\in U$ and $f\in F $. How does this help me?

Comment: Along with Connor's great hands-on answer, this can also be seen from the perspective of classifying spaces (if you know about them), as $Prin_G(X)\cong [X, BG]$ for any topological group $G$. Note that for each $X$ the set $Prin_G(X)$ contains at least the trivial principal $G$-bundle. If $G$ is the trivial group, or more generally a contractible topological group (such as $\mathbb{R}$), then $BG$ can be chosen to be a point, and so $Prin_G(X)$ is a singleton for each $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s say we’ve covered our base space of $p: Z\rightarrow X$ with a collection of trivializations, $f_i:p^{-1} (U_i ) \rightarrow U_i \times F$ and that all the transition functions are trivial.

Recall that to get the total space back from the information of the transition functions, we glue $U_i \times F$ to $U_j \times F$ by the prescription $(x,t)=(x,\theta_{j,i}(t))$ for all pairs $(i,j)$.

Since the transition functions are trivial we are gluing via the identity. We may define the function $T: Z \rightarrow X \times F$ via $z$ goes to $z’$ where we get $z’$ by taking a trivialization $f_i$ around $p(z)$ and letting $z’=f_i(z)$.

This has an inverse defined in a similar way. The fact that this is well defined follows from the fact that we glued via the identity.